# WifiManager setWifiEnabled(), continue after Wi-Fi disabled?

Tags: android, android-networking

I want to download a file using cellular data. It seems that there is no API to specify the network connection when downloading a file, so I am trying to disable Wi-Fi before download.

It seems that I can use the `setWifiEnabled` method, but the documentation does not mention whether it is blocking or not. I am assuming that it is not. Then, I must wait until the Wi-Fi is disabled before continuing to the next line.

```
val wifiManager = this.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
wifiManager.isWifiEnabled = false
(how to wait here until the system finishes disabling Wi-Fi?)
downloadFile()
```

What is the easiest way for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register a [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver) to be notified whan a WiFi connection cahnged or try:

```
private boolean isConnectedViaWifi() {
 ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) appObj.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
 NetworkInfo mWifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);     
 return mWifi.isConnected();
```

}

with:

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
    if(isConnectedViaWifi()) //download
}}, 0, 1000);
```